# How do I access a Stormpath secretKey in an 0700 dotfile directory?

Tags: express, stormpath

The recommended practice for your secretKey in Stormpath is, appropriately, to be very secretive and make sure it never ends up, for instance, in version control.

I believe that it is recommended to have it stored in a mode 0700 ~/.stormfile directory and have the top-level ?app.js? access it, but I'm not clear how one is supposed to have the app.js pull the contents of a file under a dotfile directory and store it in the relevant variable.

Given that I have a mode 0700 ~/.stormfile directory and a secret key, how do I store and access the secret key so that the ?app.js? stormpath.init() call has my secret key?

Answer (score 0):

0700 will set the file to be read-only for the current user.  Assuming you're running node as the same user, you shouldn't have a problem.  Could you elaborate on "dotfile directory"?

Comment: 0700 will set the file to be read, write, and execute for the current user. "dotfile directory" refers to a directory whose name begins with a dot, in the user's home directory (in LUM, a beginning . tucks files and directories away from a regular 'ls', although it's easy to ask to see everything in the current directory: 'ls -a'). My question is how to get Stormpath to load a secret key that I have placed in an 0700 dotfile directory. What should the JavaScript accessing the secret key be?